# Look for some text in a google site

Tags: javascript, google-sites

I have a google site with a lot of pages. Each page has a test like this:

```
Editor: Name
```

So I want to check automatically the name of the editor of all the pages with a script but I'm not good at programming...Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This Editor: Name text is within what kind of tags?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen Thanks mate. That text is just plain text in the page.

Comment: will it be possible to let me know the url of this google site so that i can just test it?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen This google site is to test it. https://sites.google.com/site/prueba123fsd/home. Thanks very much indeed

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script tag  in your code and add the following code wherever you want ,

**In JS:**

```
var divs=$("div");
for(id in divs){
if(divs[id].innerHTML.indexOf("Editor")!=-1){
alert("Editor Found , "+divs[id].innerHTML);
}
}
```

- According to your site the text "Editor: Name" is present within a
  DIV element in HTML,
- So what i have done is that i have fetched all
  DIV elements which will be a collection and then i have tried to find
  out whether the text within the DIV element contains the text
  "Editor" ,since the name will change with each page
- If the text"Editor" is found then an alert displaying the entire text within the DIV will be displayed as "Editor Found , Editor : Name"
- I have used jQuery here in case you want to use javascript then you will have to replace `var divs=$("div");` with `var divs=document.getElementsByTagName("div");`

**Note:** it would be best to add this code within a function after the page loads

Comment: First of all thank you very much for helping me. I'll try to create a script to get the name and send it to a .doc file. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please give me a vote for this answer?if this answer gave you some idea?